# Can I use a thread within a FastAPI StreamingResponse

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI where the api is responsible for creating docker instances. I would like to stream the output from creating the docker instance back to the client.

I was looking at the StreamingResponse example for sending the data to the client, however, I would like to yield the data from a thread, such that it streams out to the response. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm only as far as looking at the StreamingResponse from the fastapi website.

```
async def fake_video_streamer():
    for i in range(2):
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        yield str.encode(f"some fake video bytes {i}")

@router.post("/")
async def create_build():
    return StreamingResponse(fake_video_streamer())
```